# EL sessionScope object is getting dected in jsp due to cross domain site

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, iframe

I have developed a web app using jsp.

It is intranet website.

User can access this app from another domain web application with help of iframe.

Means in that website,my application is getting open in iframe.

They are passing there session object through request wrapper.

The problem in my jsp if I use following line then its working fine

```
request.getSession().getAttribute("smobj")
```

But if I use following line fen its not working.

```
${sessionScope.smobj}
```

Please help, and what could be the reason?

Comment: What about `${smobj}`, is `EL` enabled in your jsp?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the scope `<c:set var="smobj" scope="request" value="yourValue"/>`